# SGE array job for Python taking input from a loop

Tags: python, bash, shell, cluster-computing

I'm trying to submit array job of a Python script that should get different inputs. For now I just submit every job separately like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

P_vec=($(seq 0.92 0.01 1.15))
length_P=${#P_vec[@]}

for (( i=0; i<${length_P}; i++ ));
do
    qsub -cwd python saver.py -s ${P_vec[i]}
done
```

However, I would like to submit it as array job as I've found in this [tutorial](http://wiki.gridengine.info/wiki/index.php/Simple-Job-Array-Howto), where the basic example is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Tell the SGE that this is an array job, with "tasks" to be numbered 1 to 10000
#$ -t 1-10000
# When a single command in the array job is sent to a compute node,
# its task number is stored in the variable SGE_TASK_ID,
# so we can use the value of that variable to get the results we want:
~/programs/program -i ~/data/input.$SGE_TASK_ID -o ~/results/output.$SGE_TASK_ID
```

How can I combine the `-t` flag inside of the loop at the previous script?

Trying the following approach:

```
#!/bin/bash


P_vec=($(seq 0.92 0.01 1.15))
length_P=${#P_vec[@]}
#$ -t 1-$length_P

python saver.py -s ${P_vec[$SGE_TASK_ID]}
```

Gave the error message:

```
Unable to read script file because of error: Numerical value invalid!
The initial portion of string "$length_P" contains no decimal number
```

While this gave no error messages, but not the required output:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -t 1-3

python saver.py -s $SGE_TASK_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Cannot test it, but my common sense says:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Tell the SGE that this is an array job, with "tasks" to be numbered 0 to length_P-1
#$ -t 0-???????

P_vec=($(seq 0.92 0.01 1.15))

python saver.py -s ${P_vec[$SGE_TASK_ID]}
```

Comment: It spits out the following error message because of the `???????` : `Unable to read script file because of error: Numerical value invalid!
The initial portion of string "???????" contains no decimal number`

Comment: Errr... this is where the `length_P-1` value should be, as the comment explains.

Comment: It still gives me the error `The initial portion of string "$length_P" contains no decimal number`

Comment: This makes sense: "$length_P" is not a number. Have you tried with a number?